# Boss Battle State Machine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a boss enemy using a simple state machine for his different behaviours. I'm trying to build an Attacking and Waiting state as it is, but I'm running into some issues.

How can I make the states switch automatically? Ideally, I'd like the boss to be attacking for a specified amount of time, then waiting (at which time he is vulnerable) for another amount of time. But the waiting is the issue I'm running into. Is there a good way to go about this?

EDIT: The State machine I'm writing currently looks like this:

```
public class BossStateMachine : MonoBehaviour
{

    /* TODO: Figure out WAITING for state changes */

    private delegate void State(); //create delegate
    private State stateMethod; //create holder for delegate

    bool canBeAttacked = false;
    public int bossHealth = 5; //takes 5 hits

    /*
     * States:
     * Attacking - boss is attacking, is not vulnerable
     * Waiting - boss is not attacking, is vulnerable
     */

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        stateMethod = new State(EnterStateAttacking);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        stateMethod();
    }

    private void EnterStateAttacking()
    {
        canBeAttacked=false;
        stateMethod = new State(Attacking);
        stateMethod(); //start in same frame (comment out to delay)
    }

    private void Attacking()
    {
        FireBlast(); //method of attack
    }

    private void EnterStateWaiting()
    {
        canBeAttacked=true;
        stateMethod = new State(Waiting);
        stateMethod();
    }

    private void Waiting()
    {
        //wait (open to attack from player)
        //do laughing or something
    }
}
```

I'd like to have both the Waiting state and the Attacking state enter and exit on their own. Even through the update function, how can I do this?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information for us to help you. THe obvious question I have for you is: "Why not just update the boss' state in your game loop/Update function?".

Comment: Well the question doesn't need to be closed, I can just add more information. I've edited the question to include my current implementation, but how can I do it through Update? What sort of automatic switching could I implement such that it would wait for a certain amount of time?

Comment: +1 I don't see any reason to close this question

Comment: To be fair, I hadn't provided the code before, so it might have seemed a bit bare, but I think if people are going to vote for a question to be closed, they should say why. I'm clearly posting here for help, and closing my question rather than commenting is just not constructive.

Comment: How deep down the rabbit hole do you want to go?  I implemented a [finite state machine](http://www.seethroughskin.com/blog/?p=2036) (full disclosure: link is to my own site) in Unity but that might be overkill.  Unity Gems also has a [nice FSM write up](http://unitygems.com/fsm1/).

Comment: I guess I basically just want a way to have these states change on their own, aka with waiting of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's simplest form, you could have it switch backwards and forwards between states.. something like this:

```
private TimeSpan timeToWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000); // 5 seconds
private TimeSpan lastStateCheck;

public void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
    if (lastStateCheck + timeToWait < gameTime.TotalGameTime) {
        // switch states after 5 seconds..
        /* Switch state code here */
        lastStateCheck = gameTime.TotalGameTime;
    }
}
```

A more advanced AI would perform a lot more checks, such as whether the player has been seen, or whether it should continue to attack if the player is directly in front of it.

PS: I didn't vote to close (thought I should mention that)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might work. I've been doing a lot of reading in Unity's documentation, but sometimes I just don't know what to look for. I'm going to try this now, if I have any questions I'll post again.
(no hard feelings, of course. Furthermore, I think if people are going to vote to close, they should say why)

Comment: Alternatively [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation//ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html) are an elegant way to solve this kind of problems, especially if you don't want the code in `Update` or `FixedUpdate`

Comment: I tried coroutines for other waiting functions (so I didn't have to change the return type of any function I used the `yield WaitForSeconds` in) but they never seemed to be called (as in, no wait would occur).

Comment: @Simon, I'm having some trouble with the gameTime object you're using. I can't seem to find an equivalent for what I'm doing. Is there something you're including for this?